# Локализация пакетов

Tags: java, архитектура

Есть три класса `A`, `B`, `C`. Каждый класс лежит в своем Maven модуле.

Класс `A` создает экземпляр класса `B`, а тот создает экземпляр класса `C`. Классам  `B` и `C` нужны некоторые локализованные сообщения которые нужно выгрузить из базы и передать в некоторый интерфейс, который затем передать по цепочке `B` -> `C`. Это может сделать класс `A` или другой класс из пакета с классом `A`. Классы `B` и `C` ничего о базе не знают. Инициализацию хотелось бы сделать единоразово при загрузке классов.

Вопрос, как бы это красивей сделать? Сейчас смотрю в сторону SPI и ServiceLoader. Вроде, именно то, что мне нужно. Или есть альтернативы?

Comment: Spring вам не поможет тут?Либо обычный maven с pom, где все эти 3 модуля прописаны?

Comment: А как мне поможет maven? Кроме того `C` это особенность реализации класса 'B' и снаружи о нем знать ничего не должны. Т.е., максимум, я передаю интерфейс локализации в `B`, а тот уже сам локализует `C`

Comment: Да, в таком случае, maven не поможет(